# UICollectionView cell images keep changing while scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using CollectionView to display images of gif and png format. All the gif images are loading properly but when I scroll the CollectionView, the png images keep being replaced by other gif images.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StickerCell", for: indexPath)as! StickerCell

    let stickerString = String(describing: self.stickerArray[indexPath.row])

    if (stickerString.hasSuffix(".gif")){

        let url = self.stickerArray[indexPath.row]
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
            let image = UIImage()
            image.setGifFromData(data, levelOfIntegrity: 0.5)
            cell.sticker.setGifImage(image)
        }
    } else {

        let url = self.stickerArray[indexPath.row]
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
            cell.sticker.image = image
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have also tried using DispatchQueue.main.async, its not working either.

Comment: use SDWebImage library to loading an image : https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage It cache the image also. it didn't download image again-n again. As you had written code you download image every time with async when you scoll collection view it reusases the cell so downloaded image shown and its download new index image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to download the image data every time a collection view cell is loaded. Try using https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher for downloading and caching images. You need to download the images once and then images will get cached, which it means next time you scroll it will use cached images and you will not get anymore this issue.